# Combining two different cells containing different date values(month, year)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to combine two different cell values from an input sheet:

cell(6, k) which contains a year value as "standard", eg. "2019"

cell(7, k) which contains a month value as "date", eg. "June"

After combining, I want to convert this date to an output sheet in the format "MMM/YY", eg. "Jun/19".

Is there a way to do this without declaring the cells as integer or string values and putting the cells directly in the DateSerial function? 
That is to minimize the number of lines in the code.

I'm currently getting a "type mismatch error (#13)".

Here's what I have so far(input sheet and output sheet already declared):

```
Option Explicit
Sub formdate()  

Dim erow As Long
Dim outputsheet As Worksheet
Dim inputsheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 to 4

        erow = outputsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

        outputsheet.Cells(erow, 1) = DateSerial(inputsheet.Cells(6, i).Value, month(inputsheet.Cells(7, i).Value), 1)
        outputsheet.Cells(erow, 1).NumberFormat = "MMM/YY"

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You need a `Day` argument for `DateSerial`, I'm assuming it's 1. Also, is the month cell a `String` or an actual date that is formatted as "Mmmm"? You'll run into a type mismatch in the first case. Finally, if your year is just a year, then don't use the `Year` function. `Year(2019)` returns `1905`, not `2019`.

Comment: Right! However, even with including a day value I'm getting the same error code : #13

Comment: See the commentary about the type mismatch. `Month` doesn't like a `String`. Maybe you could use `DateValue` instead of `DateSerial`.

Comment: Btw, have noticed that over the past few days you have received some answers but have not yet marked them as answered - see [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This recognizes that the question is closed and also "rewards" the answerer for helping you out!

Comment: @BigBen my apologies. I'll be sure to do that! Thank you for all the help over the past few days. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the corresponding lines in your `For` loop thus:

```vb
    outputsheet.Cells(erow, 1) = _
         CStr(inputsheet.Cells(7, i).Value) & " " & CStr(inputsheet.Cells(6, i).Value)
    outputsheet.Cells(erow, 1).NumberFormat = "MMM/YY"
```

Comment: Above works with the addition of the missing "&" and ")". Thank you very much